# Do training breaks affect the 'novice effect'?

Tags: strength-training, starting-strength, novice

Starting Strength book mentions the ['novice effect'](http://startingstrength.com/index.php/site/article/the_novice_effect#.VNS3jp2UeAU), where a novice can gain strength very quickly and increase lifts every workout.

Does taking a break during the novice phase affects this?

Is there a 'window of opportunity' for the novice effect? Do I miss it - and consequently get to intermediate type of gains before I should - if I don't increase weight at every workout (because I missed a day, need to work on form, got sick or I'm not feeling my best)?

Comment: Someone posted a very nice answer to a question something like this. Basically after training your body starts to recover. After 2-3 days of recovering the body enters to a "phase" where the body is stronger before returning to normal in another 1-2 days. I am not 100% sure in it tho, but i guess it makes sense.As a beginner, i would go as far as picking the same weight you did last time, and if you are on the roll again, increase it.

Comment: @s3v3ns you are referring to the supercompensation phase. You might find this interesting reading. http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/core9.htm

Answer (score 2):

You might have to make a slighly restart because you're set back a miniscule amount mentally and physiologically, but you're not missing any opportunity, only delaying it.

Novice gains exist because of the (mostly neurological) differences in performance between someone who is actively working out and someone who isn't.